# Is the "display" property inherited or not?

Tags: css

This might be a silly question, but I don't understand why the `display` property (per the following link: https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/propidx.html) is not listed as inherited.

Yes, `<strong>strong</strong>` will stay `inline` (and will not turn into `block`) if we put it inside `<p>sentence</p>`, but what about `display: none`? It seems that `display: none` is a special case and in such a case the value **is** inherited? And so when we talk about the `display` property we should say that it is not inherited **except** when its value is `none`, right?

Also, are there other such properties and values? I mean the ones that are inherited in most cases, but not in all cases.

Example 1:

```html
<style>
  p { display: block; }
  strong { display: inline; }
</style>

<!-- `aaa` will stay inline -->
<p>foo <strong>aaa</strong> bar</p>
```

Example 2:

```html
<style>
  p { display: none; }
  strong { display: inline; }
</style>

<!-- `aaa` will disappear, so I think it has inherited `display: none`
from its parent. -->

<p>foo <strong>aaa</strong> bar</p>
```

Comment: Could you give an example which shows why you think it is inherited? I can't think of one.

Comment: @AHaworth I have added examples. I hope now the question is more clear.

Comment: I just thought that a display: none element didn't get rendered at all (and that includes its children) so what the display setting for a child is isn't relevant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because of [the way `display:none` is defined.](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/visuren.html#display-prop)

> This value causes an element to not appear in the formatting structure (i.e., in visual media the element generates no boxes and has no effect on layout). Descendant elements do not generate any boxes either

The child elements aren't inheriting `display:none` from the parent element.

If they were, a child element with `display:block !important` would cause a contradiction. The parent element would not be displayed, but the child element (inside the parent) would be, so the child should both be displayed and not displayed at the same time.

Comment: Schrödinger's element.

Comment: You can't tell whether the element is displayed or not until it receives `:focus`.